# Question about the GNS representation

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I get stuck on Murphy's book $C^*$ Algebras and Operator Theory, Page 95.

First, for a $C^*$ algebra $A$, he defines a closed left ideal $N_\tau = \{ a\in A: \tau(a^*a) = 0 \}$ then, he defines an inner product on the quotient algebra $A/N_\tau$ by $(a + N_\tau, b + N_\tau) = \tau(b^*a)$. Then the Hilbert completion of $A/N_\tau$ is denoted as $H_\tau$. For $a \in A$ he defines the operator $\varphi(a)$ on $A/N_\tau$ by $\varphi(a)(b + N_\tau) = ab + N_\tau$. 
Then it's bounded and can be extended to an bounded operator on $H_\tau$. Then the map
$$ \varphi_\tau: A \to B(H_\tau), a\mapsto \varphi_\tau(a) $$ is a *-homomorphism.

My question is that how to show this map is a *-homomorphism, more concretely, how to show
$$ \varphi(a^*) = \varphi(a)^* $$

I try to show for any $c + N_\tau$:
$$ a^*c + N_\tau = (ac+ N_\tau)^* = c^*a^* + N_\tau $$
But I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \varphi(a)^*\hat c,\hat c\rangle
&=\langle \hat c,\varphi(a)\hat c\rangle
=\langle \hat c,\widehat{ac}\rangle\\[0.3cm]&=\tau((ac)^*c)=\tau(c^*(a^*c))\\[0.3cm]&=\langle\widehat a^*c,\hat c\rangle
=\langle \varphi(a^*)\hat c,\hat c\rangle. 
\end{align}
$$
As this works for any $c\in A$ and $\{\hat c:\ c\in A\}$ is dense, we get that $\varphi(a)^*=\varphi(a^*)$.

Comment: Do you mean the $\hat{c}$ is the representative element of $c + N_\tau$?

Comment: It is fairly common to write $\hat c=c+N_\tau$.

Comment: Okay, I got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)